# Can we define boolean without a value?

Tags: c, boolean

Can we define boolean without a value?

[image]

Comment: C is not C++. There is no `bool` type in C. The best you can get is `_Bool` surrogate from boolean type support library (part of C99 extensions). Also see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @user7860670 *There is no `bool` type in C...* [You might want to rethink that statement](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.18).  IMO that counts as it's not syntactically different from a true `bool` type from the point of the code actually written.

Comment: The presence of `conio.h` indicates the use of TurboC, a seriously ***old*** compiler. If that's the case, you probably won't find `stbool` in there and should move to a more modern one.

Comment: @paxdiablo This isn't TC, it's VS Code or some such. Though in case MSVC is used as compiler, it might very well be as old as Turbo C (they only added C99 support around 2017 somewhere), so the same arguments about lack of standard C compliance apply.

Answer (score 2):

To use Boolean variables in C you need to `#include <stdbool.h>` in your headers.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of error you get? I just tried your code with the added header #include <stdbool.h> and it compiles fine. Of course it doesn't produce any output, but that's because so far you have only declared three variables and not done anything else.

Comment: That depends on your definition of boolean values. If you mean `bool`, then you're right. But I still consider `int hasFinished = 0;` to be a "boolean" variable, despite its type.

Answer (score 0):

You can very much define a boolean variable without a value, as evidenced by the following code (but note the second header include, see below for explanation):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main (void) {
    bool u, t = true, f = false;

    if (t) puts("t is true"); else puts("t is false");
    if (f) puts("f is true"); else puts("f is false");
    if (u) puts("u is true"); else puts("u is false");

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs (for me):

```
t is true
f is false
u is false
```

However, you should be aware of the normal rules regarding initialisation of variables where you don't make it explicit. In the code given, `u` will hold some *arbitrary* value and, indeed, using a higher warning level of `gcc` makes that clear:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:8:8: warning: ‘u’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    8 |     if (u) puts("u is true"); else puts("u is false");
      |        ^
```

---

Note that, if you want to use `bool`, `true`, and `false`, these are *not* keywords, they're instead defined in the `stdbool` header file so you need to include that.

Otherwise all you get is the `_Bool` type<sup>(1)</sup> and neither of the nice constants, so you'll have to define some yourself or use `0` and `1` (although any non-zero value converts to `1`).

Since this is scarcely a step up for doing the same thing with `int`, you probably want to do it properly (i.e., use the header).

---

Note further that this is only available as of C99. The presence of an `#include <conio.h>` in your code *may* indicate that you're using a hideously outdated implementation of C (it was a common header for DOS-era compilers such as Turbo C).

If that *is* the case, it's likely you don't even *have* a `stdbool` header that you can use, so you'll have to stick with `int`, `0`, and `1`.

Alternatively, you may be able to create your own `my_stdbool.h` such as the following, assuming there's no naming conflict as previously mentioned (most code I've seen that defines the constants tends to use the upper-case `FALSE` and `TRUE` in keeping with commonly-used guidelines):

```c
#ifndef XYZZY_STDBOOL_H_INCLUDED
    #define XYZZY_STD_BOOL_H_INCLUDED
    typedef bool int;
    #define false 0
    #define true  1
#endif
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Uglier, yes, but it ensures there's no clash between code that may have been written before this became part of the standard since names beginning with `_X` (where `X` is any upper-case letter or another `_`) are reserved for the implementation. Hence you shouldn't be using them.

Answer (score -3):

In C, you can declare a boolean variable using the **_Bool** type. Following as an example. However, it is not a recommended method.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    _Bool k=0, l = 1, m = 324234;
    printf("%d\n", k);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

You can further use a macro to define `_Bool` as `bool`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef _Bool bool;
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    bool k=0, l = 1, m = 324234;
    printf("%d\n", k);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef _Bool bool;?`?  Just use `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: I agree @AndrewHenle. I had thought of adding that. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Why are you assigning `324234` to a boolean type? Or, indeed, *any* integer. You should be including `stdbool.h` and using `true/false`. I know you *can* do this but there are plenty of things you can do but *shouldn't* :-)

Comment: It was just to imply that _Bool is true for any non-zero data. Yes @paxdiablo, I understood  your concern.